# Serialize BEFORE the mysql_fetch_array?

Tags: php, mysql, serialization, memcached

I'm trying to use memcache but I'm stuck on a small part. I've got a function that gives in result an array of several things (most of them being strings), and one of them is the result of the mysql_query() function. 
Here is how I am trying to unserialize:

```
    $posts_count = my query;                

    /* MEMCACHE KEY GEN*/
    $memcache_key = md5($posts);
    $pagination = memcache_get($memcache, $memcache_key);
    if($pagination==NULL) {
        echo 'NOT CACHED';
        $pagination = (the function that will call mysql_query)
        //SAVE A SERIALIZED VERSION OF THE ARRAY
        $memcache->set($memcache_key, serialize($pagination), 0, 3600); 
    }
    else {
        $pagination = unserialize($pagination);
    }

    //THIS IS ONLY THE RESULT OF mysql_query!!!     

    $posts = $pagination[result]; 
    while($var = mysql_fetch_array($posts)) { ... stuffs here }
```

Any idea on how to "save" this result of mysql_query before the mysql_fetch_array? Or any idea how to use memcache to cache the whole while loop?

Comment: You cannot serialize a resource. End of.

Comment: Ok, but then is there a way to use memcache in a while loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
$posts_count = "my query";                

/* MEMCACHE KEY GEN*/
$memcache_key = md5($posts);
$pagination = memcache_get($memcache, $memcache_key);
if ($pagination == NULL) {
  echo 'NOT CACHED';
  $pagination = function_that_will_call_mysql_query();
  // Create an array of all the results
  $data = array();
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($pagination['result'])) {
    $data[] = $row;
  }
  $pagination['result'] = $data;
  //SAVE A SERIALIZED VERSION OF THE ARRAY
  $memcache->set($memcache_key, serialize($pagination), 0, 3600); 
} else {
    $data = unserialize($pagination);
}

// THIS IS ONLY THE RESULT OF mysql_query!!! (but now it's an array)

$posts = $pagination['result']; 
while ($var = array_shift($posts)) {
  // ... do stuff here
}
```

Comment: Was going to suggest something similar but the OP is pretty confusing. Hopefully it sticks.

Comment: That's perfect! I would never have thought of array_shift ! Thanks a lot ! :)

Comment: Hey @DaveRandom Please check out this : 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9798949/php-serialize-function-adding-serialized-data-to-mysql-and-then-fetch-and-disp 

If you can help...